# View with score

Tags: mysql

I've such relation with tables

[image]

I want to create view in which every user get for example 10 points for first place in race, 9 point for second place etc. In table played_race I have id_player, id_race and time user has in this race. In table race I've filed race_end_date so I can select all played race which date is less than current date.

This sql statement

```
SELECT player.login, race.race_name, played_race.race_time
FROM player
INNER JOIN  `played_race` ON player.id_player = played_race.id_player
INNER JOIN  `race` ON played_race.id_race = race.id_race
WHERE race.race_end_date < CURDATE( ) 
ORDER BY race.id_race, played_race.race_time
```

Give me list all finished races but how use this to create score tables. I think I have to use count and group by but I don't have idea how to do it correctly. Do I have make very large sql statment where I group and sum results for example in first sum all first places and group by id_user and that same for other nine places. Any help gladly welcome ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can run this query first to set the value of a variable:
`SET @Score := 10;`

Then run your query with these modifications:

```
SELECT player.login, race.race_name, played_race.race_time, (@Score := @Score - 1) as Score
FROM player
INNER JOIN  `played_race` ON player.id_player = played_race.id_player
INNER JOIN  `race` ON played_race.id_race = race.id_race
WHERE race.race_end_date < CURDATE( ) 
ORDER BY race.id_race, played_race.race_time
```